# Fatal error: Call to a member function when Mocking on PHPSpec

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-4, phpspec

This is the code that i am trying to test

```
    public function forgot($email)
{
    try
    {
        // Find the user using the user email address
        $user =$this->sentry->findUserByLogin($email);

        $resetCode = $user->getResetPasswordCode();

         return true;
    }
    catch (UserNotFoundException $e)
    {
        $this->errors[] = 'User was not found.';

        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is my testing code

```
  function it_should_forgot(Sentry $sentry)
{
    $email = 'johndavedecano@gmail.com';

    $sentry->findUserByLogin($email)->shouldBeCalled();

    $this->forgot($email);
}
```

Here is the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getResetPasswordCode() on a non-object in /var/www/laravel/app/Services/SentryService.php on line 103
```

My question is why am i getting this error as i have already mock sentry inside my test?

Comment: So where do you mock what `findUserByLogin` returns?

Comment: Please enlighten me how it should be done. Thanks

Comment: Well, look at your test method and tell what according to it the `findUserByLogin` method should return.

Comment: $sentry->findUserByLogin('johndavedecano@test.com')->willReturn($user); please let me know if this is correct

Comment: What if you try first? Stackoverflow is not intended to be a syntax checker

Comment: It resolves the method now. But  it should forgot
      expected false, but got null.

Comment: Why do you call getResetPasswordCode if the return value is not used?

Answer (score 0):

There's no mocking requried here. You only need stubs (`Sentry`) and dummies (`User`):

```php
function it_returns_true_if_user_is_found(Sentry $sentry, User $user)
{
    $email = 'johndavedecano@gmail.com';

    $sentry->findUserByLogin($email)->willReturn($user);

    $this->forgot($email)->shouldReturn(true);
}

function it_returns_false_if_user_is_not_found(Sentry $sentry)
{
    $email = 'johndavedecano@gmail.com';

    $sentry->willThrow(new UserNotFoundException())->duringFindUserByLogin($email);

    $this->forgot($email)->shouldReturn(false);
}
```

**Recommended reading**:

- [PHP Test Doubles Patterns with Prophecy](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2013/07/23/php-test-doubles-patterns-with-prophecy/)
- [Mocking Demistified](http://www.slideshare.net/marcello.duarte/mocking-demystified)
- [Conceptual difference between Mockery and Prophecy](http://everzet.com/post/72910908762/conceptual-difference-between-mockery-and-prophecy)